# Prepend using variables posted

Tags: jquery, ajax, prepend

I have a form which posts using ajax therefore no page refresh

When the form has posted I want to prepend the html show using some of the variables the user has just posted.

So, a field named comment, I want to add the comment to the db and then prepend the html to show the comment at the top, but how do I use the variable the user has just posted?

the form has text input named comment - i take the comment:

```
var comment = $("#comment").val();
```

Then send it to a php script for adding into db

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST", // form method
url: "/pages/test/test_comments.php",// destination
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
```

Then I want to prepend the comments to the top of the div (id=test) - I;'ve tried:

```
$('#test').prepend('<div style="width:100%; overflow:auto;">comment</div>');
```

And also

```
$('#test').prepend('<div style="width:100%; overflow:auto;">'comment'</div>');
```

But neither work as they should - is this possible or is there a better way?

Comment: did you forget the `+` in string concat?

Comment: This question could be written in one or two lines.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a syntax error, you should use `+` for concatenating:

```
$('#test').prepend('<div style="width:100%; overflow:auto;">' + comment + '</div>');
```